# GLES2 glTexStorage doesn't work on Nexus 7 2013?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0

How I used `glTexStorage`

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <gl2ext.h>
```

So `glTexStorage2DEXT` is direct symbol.
However I also checked `eglGetProcAddress()`, they are the same address.

Code snippet :

```
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Then this gives `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` on `glTexSubImage2D`:

```
glTexStorage2DEXT(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8_OES, w, h);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

But this doesn't give error:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

What's wrong with my use of `glTexStorage2DEXT`?

Answer (score 0):

Stop using the extension.  It is a standard part of GL ES 3 (which the nexus 7 supports) so just use:

```
glTexStorage2D
```

(ie without the EXT!)

Comment: I am currently targeting ES2, because I don't know how to cleanly handle ES2/3 in one native program.  
(I don't quite like the ndk gles3 sample which have the whole rendering implemented twice in ES2/3.)  
If I include ES3 .h and avoid ES3-only API/format calls at runtime, can my program run on ES2 devices?